# Ubuntu Start Page in Firefox Language changed suddenly

Tags: firefox, language-support

Suddenly on the Ubuntu Start Page in Firefox English has been changed to Spanish. How do I reset to English?

Comment: Can you clarify what start page you are referring to?

Comment: Do you mean the log-in screen for the graphical desktop session? The Grub boot menu? The Ubuntu-flavoured Google page that appears as the default home page of Firefox in Ubuntu?

Comment: He means the Ubuntu Start Page in Firefox if I'm not mistaken as I had the same problem.

Comment: Just to clarify: is this what you are talking about? http://imgur.com/SQfUlVb

Answer (score 5):

Looks similar to these:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1669853
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1352219

Try typing in `about:config` into the url bar, then adjusting this:

```
intl.accept_languages
```

Comment: The languages set as default are en-us, en. Problem with Firefox Ubuntu still there. No problem with Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I was also affected by this problem. The only language support I have installed is English and there was no change to menus, just the firefox about:start page (default home page). The problem persisted after a reboot.

I opened System Settings->Language Support to check for any changes on the Language tab and found none.

I switched to the Regional Formats tab and all was set as expected:

[image: langsupport]

I clicked the Apply Systemwide button and the problem disappeared and didn't reappear after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just change the homepage setting in firefox and not use the "about:startpage", it's main function is google anyway, so setting the homepage to www.google.com is effective at resolving the issue.